# Internet radio statio playing Spotify for private use

Tags: streaming, metadata, spotify, icecast, internet-radio

I want to build a server that I can register as my own internet radio station on my hardware internet radio player using wifiradiofrontier.com. Reasoning: I want to listen to Spotify when I wake up and there is no hardware internet radio that can play Spotify triggered by an alarm.

I think of the following setup on an Ubuntu machine:

Spotify client which connects to Spotify and plays a fixed playlist. Control via Smartphone over Spotify Connect would be a nice extra.

Audio and hopefully metadata are then transferred to IceCast2 or something similar. I am not sure on how to do that. For audio I could use Jack I suppose but how can I transfer audio and metadata?

Once the data is in IceCast2 I can just set it up as webradio, register it on wifiradiofrontier.com and there we go.

Any thoughts on this? Has somebody done this before?

Comment: Can your hardware player use a custom address?  Or, must the stream URL you add be public?

Comment: Custom address should be possible I think.